# Having issue with kdbg not displaying prompt

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, driver, windbg

I'm trying to debug Windows drivers on Windows XP virtual machines through VirtualBox from a Mac.

I'm having little to no luck getting WinDbg's `kd` command prompt so I can actually run commands. The last time I got the command prompt, it took 10 minutes from boot up to appear.

The virtual machine boots up just fine, but then the system just kind of hangs. Even when debugging on Windows 7 virtual machines the command prompt takes a very long time to display. Am I doing anything wrong? My baud rate is 112500 and I'm debugging through a host pipe through COM1.

Comment: With "kdbg" do you mean the kernel debugger from WinDbg or a separate product?

Comment: Other than that, the COM port *is* slow. Did you try http://virtualkd.sysprogs.org/

Comment: @ThomasWeller I mean kd.exe included in the winddk debugger suite. Virtualkd would be sweet, but I'm on a mac.